# Local Memory Corruption

Tags: opencl

I have a question about local memory usage across work items:

I have a workgroup with 256 work items in it. I would like to assign K bytes of local memory per work item.

So, I create a local byte array of size 256 * K, and assign one region of size K to each work item.

In the code, each work item only accesses its own region in the array. Can I be guaranteed that work items do not somehow access another work items region?  Given the fact that local memory is shared across half wavefronts?

The reason I ask is that I am seeing this sort of corruption, but I am not sure if it is a code bug, or a problem with my design;

i.e. using a shared local array, shared among work items.

Comment: Yes, this turned out to be true. Move this to an answer, and I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given the fact that local memory is shared across half wavefronts

I am not sure what you mean by that, but the OpenCL spec states very clearly that local memory is shared across a *work-group*. There is no such concept as "half wavefront" (nor even wavefront) as far as the standard is concerned.

Any memory corruption you may notice can have only been introduced by your own code: it is your responsibility that your kernels do not exhibit any data races.

Comment: Turns out the problem was: I was casting a local pointer of type uchar to a pointer of type ulong, and due to aliasing ( I guess), the memory was being corrupted.